# How can I stop Greenshot from automatically zooming in when I press “print screen?”

Tags: greenshot

[Greenshot](https://getgreenshot.org) automatically zooms when I press <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>.

How do I turn this of so I can select from the whole screen?

I have looked through all settings and FAQs on the website but there doesn't seem to be a way to change it.

Answer (score 3):

Are you referring to the magnifying glass that appears when taking a screenshot? If so, you can turn that off by pressing <kbd>Z</kbd> (after pressing <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> to take a screenshot). This setting is persisted, so after you turn it off it will stay off for future screenshots.
Source: https://getgreenshot.org/help/#capture-region

However, if all you want is to capture the entire screen, I'd recommend the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> shortcut which does exactly that.
Source: https://getgreenshot.org/help/#capture-fullscreen